# g++: CreateProcess: No such file or directory. Can't find solution

Tags: c++, g++, raytracing

Edit: whoops. Forgot to put the correct link while formatting

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbhOJDHNp1U) tutorial, but I have gotten an error I can't fixed (I've looked at my code and then back at his for around 25 minutes. I'm sure it's not a typo anywhere)

```
C:\Users\badfitz66\Rastering>make
g++     makefile.cpp   -o makefile
g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
make: *** [makefile] Error 1
```

The code of makefile.cpp is:

```
OBJ = main.o
INC = -I "./"

Rastering: $(OBJ)
  g++ $(OBJ) -o Rastering.exe
    rm -f $(OBJ)

main.o:
    g++ -c main.cpp $(INC)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) Rastering
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `-o makefile` it means you want your C++ compiler to write its output to a file named `makefile`.  Since Windows has case-insensitive file systems, that is a very bad idea because you will end up overwriting your Makefile, which should be named `Makefile`.

Also, you seem very confused about the difference between a Makefile and a C++ file.  The file you posted is a Makefile, so it should be named `Makefile`, not `makefile.cpp`.  You will need to have at least two files: `Makefile`, and `main.cpp`.  If you want more help, you will have to show us the full contents of both of those files and the exact output you get when you run `make`.

The error `g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory` is usually caused by your toolchain not being installed properly.  You will need to install a C++ compiler that provides an executable named `g++.exe` and make sure that you add the directory with `g++.exe` in it to your PATH environment variable.  The tutorial video you linked to ought to tell you how to do that.